# Doctrine2 fetch 5 copy of each record

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a very basic table with few columns. It has `15 records` in it.

Now, if i use this `query`:

```
SELECT * FROM excursions WHERE lang_id = 1
```

It returns `5` records **as i expected**.

But, when i use doctrine2, it creates a query like this:

```
SELECT
e0_.idx AS idx0,
e0_.place_id AS place_id1,
e0_.lang_id AS lang_id2,
e0_.excursion_name AS excursion_name3,
e0_.excursion_type AS excursion_type4,
e0_.excursion_text_short AS excursion_text_short5,
e0_.start_date AS start_date6,
e0_.end_date AS end_date7,
e0_.override_place AS override_place8,
e0_.languages AS languages9,
e0_.meeting_place AS meeting_place10,
e0_.excursion_text AS excursion_text11,
e0_.starts_at AS starts_at12,
e0_.category_id AS category_id13,
e0_.map_link AS map_link14,
e0_.capacity AS capacity15,
e0_.pick_up_time AS pick_up_time16,
e0_.is_activity AS is_activity17
FROM excursions e1_, excursions e0_
WHERE e0_.lang_id = 1
```

Now, when i execute this, it returns `25 records`! `5 copy for each record`. They are exactly same but instead of `5` it returns `25` records. (**5x5**)

Oh yes, if i remove `excursions e1_` it returns 5 records totally. But why?

Can anyone look at that query, did i miss something here?

I used `QueryBuilder()`.

```
$qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('Excursions');
$qb->select('e')->from('Web\Bundle\ExcursionBundle\Entity\Excursions', 'e');
$qb->andWhere("e.langId = 1");
```

**Note**: I did other styles with or without `QueryBuilder()`. Results are always same. PHP got `1` copy of each. Query that i execute on server side gets `5` copy of each record.

I am asking this because, if doctrine gets multiple times, what if i fetch my whole table like `500` records? It will probably grab `500x5`. **Wouldn't be slowdown the process?**

Comment: Every layer of indirection comes with a price. ORM does always slow things down compared to just query the database specifically. So I guess you don't ask here specifically for speed (because *that outcome is obvious* I'd say) but probably how to do a different query strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not needed line. The correct code would be:

```
$qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('e');
$qb->andWhere("e.langId = 1");
```

What you do in your code is adding the "`from`" part twice. Once it is done by Doctrine when you execute "`createQueryBuilder`" method (it adds "`select`" and "`from`" itself). You pass the alias "`Excursions`" which is never used. Then you add the second "`from`" with alias "`e`".

Comment: See, i knew i miss something. I am blind, no, really, blind! Removing unnecessary from() solves the problem. Thank you Gedrox to make me awake.